# Dynamically changing CSV data source using ApplyLogOnInfo

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have a .rpt file that I have created by setting it's data source as a text (csv) file using the (Access/Excel (DAO) ) option.
Now I want the same .rpt file loaded using a C# code and each time my C# code will change the input file and I want a new report to be generated based on the data in the new text file.

I am doing the following code and when I export the file to a pdf document, it still displays the data according to the data in the old input file.

I have checked off the option in the .rpt file that says "save data with report" and "verify on first refresh".

What am I missing here?

CODE:

```
            cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(reportfile);

            Tables tables = cryRpt.Database.Tables;
            TableLogOnInfo tableLogonInfo;

            foreach (Table table in cryRpt.Database.Tables)
            {
                tableLogonInfo = table.LogOnInfo;
                tableLogonInfo.TableName = "MYdata_BS_NEW#csv";
                table.Location = "MYdata_BS_NEW#csv";
                table.ApplyLogOnInfo(tableLogonInfo);
            }

            cryRpt.Refresh();
```

// After this I export the report to pdf document.

Comment: you may need to force the connection type to ConnectionInfo.Type = ConnectionInfoType.DBFile